# Why sort() function causes compilation error when it is used for set of class objects

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I tried to overload `<` operator for class and called the function as follows:

```
bool Edge::operator<(Edge const & e) const {
    return this->GetCost() < e.GetCost();
}
```

in main()

```
sort(edge_set.begin(),edge_set.end());
```

In addition, I also tried to write a simple comparator function for the objects, defined in main.cpp and tried to invoke `sort()`, however failed again:

```
bool edge_comparator(Edge& e1, Edge& e2){
    return (e1.GetCost() < e2.GetCost());
}
```

in main()

```
sort(edge_set.begin(),edge_set.end(), edge_comparator);
```

I get a compilation error for those what I tried. What am I doing wrong here? How can I sort the set of objects?

Comment: how is `edge_set` defined ?

Comment: How is edge_set defined? If edge_set is a `std::set` then *it's already sorted*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems. First, you cannot reorder the elements of a set.  Their ordering criteria is determined upon construction, it is a fundamental part of the object.  This is necessary in order for it to achieve O(log n) lookups, insertions, and deletions, which is part of the promises of `std::set`.  By default, it will use `std::less<Edge>`, which should call your `operator<`.  But you could also use your `edge_comparator` function, like this:

```
std::set<Edge, bool(*)(Edge&,Edge&)> edge_set(edge_comparator);
```

Second, `std::sort` can only be used on random access iterators or better, and `std::set` iterators are bi-directional.

Comment: I see it should be sorted when adding objects to the set. I updated the question can you please re-see it?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli: You completely changed the question.  Don't do that, it invalidates the answers.  If you have a different question, make a different post.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` is a sorted associative container, so it cannot be re-sorted. The sorting criterion is applied on construction and on element insertion.

**Edit**: You have a set of `Edge` pointers. If you want this to be sorted according to your own criteria, you can instantiate an [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) with the type of a functor that performs a less-than comparison between a pair of `Edge` pointers as second template argument:

```
struct EdgePtrCmp
{
  bool operator()(const Edge* lhs, const Edge* rhs) const
  {
    return lhs->GetCost() < rhs->GetCost();
  }
}
```

then

```
std::set<Edge*, EdgePtrCmp> s;
```

**Edit 2**: The question has been changed again, so it is not clear whether it deals with a set of pointers or not.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli OK, see edit. But the question is now quite different to the original :)

Comment: You can't overload `operator<` unless at least one of the parameters is a class type (or maybe enum works also, not sure).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Of course, thanks.  What was I thinking? I've changed it to an example with a functor.