# Why isn't this set of custom objects constructed sorted according to overloaded opreator <

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, set

I have an Edge class defined as follows

```
class Edge {
public:
    //constructors & destructors
    Edge();
    Edge(const Edge& orig);
    virtual ~Edge();
    Edge(unsigned const int, const string&, const string&);

    //getters & setters
    unsigned int GetCost() const {return cost;}

    //member functions
    bool operator<(const Edge*) const;
private:
    unsigned int cost;  //cost of the edge
    string cities[2];   //cities that the edge connect
};

//cpp file
bool Edge::operator<(const Edge* e) const {
    cout << "edge" << endl;  //function is never invoked
    return this->cost < e->GetCost();
}
```

I want to keep those Edges (that are initially contained in a vector) in an Edge* set, and the corresponding code from main() is:

```
set<Edge*> edge_set;
vector<Edge*> edges;

print_vector(edges);
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
while(edge_set.size() < K){ //randomly pick K edges that will form the tree
    edge_set.insert(edges[rand()%edges.size()]);
}
print_set(edge_set);
```

and I get the output:

```
Edge vector:
edges[0] cost = 136
edges[1] cost = 558
edges[2] cost = 872
edges[3] cost = 1615
edges[4] cost = 654
edges[5] cost = 994
.
.
.

Edge set:
858
1242
436
636
804
```

I tried to define a function for overloading `<` operator in main as well, but I couldn't manage to get this set sorted that way either, i.e. couldn't get the overloaded `<` operator invoked. Also note that I different type of parameters (reference, pointer, object itself) for overloading `<`.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I already explained this to you and gave a solution in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925976/why-sort-function-causes-compilation-error-when-it-is-used-for-set-of-class-ob/15926027#15926027).

Comment: oh, now I understood. Sorry about that, I upped your question tho. Clearly I wasn't thinking right. Now I see its the exact answer. Sorry again, I was pretty new to the topic thus couldn't understand the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `operator <` for both pointers. Since it's unreal by language rules and your operator is for object and pointer - default one (`std::less<Edge*>`) will be used.
You can store objects, or you can write your functor, that will works with pointers and use it (`set` object should be declared like `std::set<Edge*, Functor>`).

Like this

```
struct CompareCost : public std::binary_function<const Edge*, const Edge*, bool>
{
   result_type operator () (first_argument_type f, second_argument_type s)
   {
      return f->operator <(s);
   }
};

std::set<Edge*, CompareCost> edge_set;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I have a few questions for this answer tho:
Why did you use inheritance for the struct? what is `std::binary_function<>` ?  Why does the operator has a return type of `result_type` and the arguments have `first_argument_type` and `second_argument_type`? Why didn't you write directly `bool`, `const Edge*`, `const Edge*` instead of them?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function. You can not inherit from `std::binary_function` if you want.